# Simplify $\tan^{-1}\Big[\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\Big]$, where $x<\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Write in the simplist form

> $$
> \tan^{-1}\bigg[\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\bigg],\quad x<\pi
> $$

**My Attempt:**
$$
x<\pi\implies -x>-\pi\implies \frac{\pi}{4}-x>\frac{-3\pi}{4}
$$
$$
\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}=\frac{\cos 2x}{1+2\sin x\cos x}=\frac{\cos 2x}{1+\sin 2x}\\=\frac{\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-2x)}{1+\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-2x)}=\frac{2\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-x)\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-x)}{2\cos^2(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-x)}={\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-x)}\\
\implies {\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-x)}=\tan\big[\tan^{-1}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\big]\\
\implies \tan^{-1}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}-x
$$
If $-\pi/2<\frac{\pi}{4}-x<\pi/2$,
$$
\tan^{-1}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{\pi}{4}-x
$$

this is what is given as answer.

But, since we have further restricted the domain to $\frac{-\pi}{2}<\frac{\pi}{4}-x<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies\frac{-\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$ from $x<\pi$, how can it be same as the original function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given expression is defined for $x\neq \frac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi$ with the given condition $x<\pi$.

When you simplify the expression by $\arctan$ you need to restrict the domain to $\frac{-\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$ which is not in contrast with the initial one.

Thus I don't see any kind of problem with your answer.

Comment: srry. i didnt get ur point. i have already written it in the original post. pls check

Comment: alright. my actual doubt is since we further restrict the domain. how can i clain the final answer is the simplified form for the given $x<\pi$ ?. The simplified form is only applicable for the restricted domain right?

Comment: @ss1729 Yes the second expression is equivalent to a restricted domain since the $\arctan$ function is defined by a restriction. You could define another $\arctan$ function (with different range) and get another range of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the given answer seems strange, as the usual range of the $\tan^{-1}$ function is $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, and if $\frac{3\pi}4 \leq x < \pi$ then $\frac\pi4-x$ is not in this range. I think you have the domain right.

Comment: it is given $x<\pi$ that means $\frac{\pi}{4}-x>\frac{-3\pi}{4}$. my doubt is the given function is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ only when we restrict $\frac{-\pi}{2}<\frac{\pi}{4}-x<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \frac{-\pi}{4}<x<\frac{3\pi}{4}$ from the given $x<\pi\implies\frac{\pi}{4}-x>\frac{-3\pi}{4}$. Since we further restrict the domain, how does the final answer true for all $x<\pi$ ?

Comment: @ss1729 I agree with you. My point was that this incongruity is evident even before working out the problem, just looking at the ranges of the given function and the given answer.